# The implication $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(w-3)^2}<b\implies |xyzw-6|<a$

Tags: inequality

Given a real number $a>0$ find a $b>0$ such that

$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(ω-3)^2}<b\Longrightarrow |xyzω-6|<a$

I tried the procedure followed in [another one of my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1245474/23353), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Call $P=(x,y,z,w)\in\Bbb R^4$ and $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)\in\Bbb R^4$.

You're asking, given $a>0$ for what values of $b>0$ we have that
$$
||P-P_0||<b\Longrightarrow |xyzw-x_0y_0z_0w_0|<a\;\;.
$$
Try to reason geometrically.

Comment: i am completely lost

Comment: Mine one was only a suggest, and I'm not sure it yelds somewhere. If what you see is arab, then ignore it.

Comment: However what you wrote, on the right side, is the interior of a disk in the 4-dimensional real space (try to think at the same object in the plane) of center $(2,1,1,3)$ and radius $b$. The second inequality says the distance between the product of the coordinates of the points which stay inside the disk described above (the points are $(x,y,z,w)$, $x,y,z,w$ are the coordinates) and the product of the coordinates of the center (the center is $(2,1,1,3)$, so the product of the coordinates is $2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot3=6$) is, in absolute value, less then $a$.

Comment: My suggest: try to figure this problem out in the case of the plane, i.e. when you have only 2 coordinates, and you have the possibility of drawing what you're doing. Try, draw, understand how the objects behave, and this could be a first way to understand the problem.
If you instead need an analytical solution, then you have to handle the first inequality in order to express it in terms of $xyzw,\;6$ and $b$, in order to connect your computation with the second inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

The question seems to be a numerical adjustment of the continuity of multiplication.  Assume that $$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(w-3)^2}<b.$$ Then $|x-2|<b$, $|y-1|<b$, $|z-1|<b$, and $|w-3|<b$.

We have $2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 3=6$ and

$$|xyzw-6|\le$$ $$|xyzw-xyz\cdot 3|+|xyz\cdot 3-xy\cdot 2\cdot 3|+$$ $$|xy\cdot 2\cdot 3 - x\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3|+
|x\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3- 1\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3|=$$ $$
|xyz|\cdot|w-3|+|xy||z-2|\cdot 3+|x||y-1|\cdot 2\cdot 3+
|x- 1|\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3<$$ $$|xyz|\cdot b+|xy|\cdot b\cdot 3+|x|\cdot b \cdot 6+
b \cdot 6.$$

If we additionally assume that $b<1$ then $1<x<3$,  $0<y<2$, $0<z<2$, and $2<w<4$. Hence

$$|xyz|\cdot b+|xy|\cdot b\cdot 3+|x|\cdot b \cdot 6+b \cdot 6<
3\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot b+3\cdot 2\cdot b\cdot 3+3\cdot b \cdot 6+b \cdot 6=
54b.$$

Thus it suffices to put $b=\min\{1, a/54\}$.

**Update**. Such breaking down is a standard trick, used in analysis and based on the triangle inequality.

The usage of $\min$ is a standard and simple act to show that $b$ should be small. The smallness is typical here,   because the continuity of function in a point is based on its behavior in small neighborhoods of this point. If we reject this approach, we may obtain a formula for $b$, which uses a polynomials or roots of $a$ and which is more complex than the minimum of a constant and a linear function.

For instance,  we have $|x|<2+b$, $|y|<1+b$, $|z|<1+b$, and $|w|<3+b$. Then

$$|xyz|\cdot b+|xy|\cdot b\cdot 3+|x|\cdot b \cdot 6+b \cdot 6<$$
$$(2+b)(1+b)^2\cdot b+(2+b)(1+b)\cdot b\cdot 3+(2+b)\cdot b \cdot 6+b \cdot 6=$$ $$
b(b^3+13b^2+23b+17)<b(b^3+15b^2+75b+125) = b(b+5)^3.$$

Then for the given $a$ we have to find $b$ such that  $b(b+5)^3<a$. It suffices to put $b=\frac a{a+6^3}$. Indeed,

$$\frac a{a+6^3}\left(\frac a{a+6^3}+5\right)^3<\frac a{a+6^3}6^3<a.$$

We can deal with your next inequality as follows. Put $$f=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}.$$ For given $a>0$ similarly to the above we find positive $b_1, b_2, b_3$ such that

$f<b_1$ implies $|x^2yz−4|<a/\sqrt{3},$

$f<b_2$ implies $|xy^2z−2|<a/\sqrt{3},$

$f<b_3$ implies $|xyz^2−2|<a/\sqrt{3}.$

Then if $f<\min\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ we have $$\sqrt{(x^2yz−4)^2+(x y^2z−2)^2+(xyz^2−2)^2}<\sqrt{3\cdot a^2/3}=a.$$

If you insist on avoiding $\min$, you can put $b=\frac{b_1b_2b_3}{b_1b_2+b_1b_3+b_2b_3}<\min\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.

Comment: yes exactly so.

Comment: But i'd like to know  the incentive that led you to the breaking down of the xyzw algebraic expression. And since it looks like you are an expert in inequalities please help me with the following inequality

Given $a>0$ find $b>0$ such that 

${\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}<b\implies \sqrt{(x^2yz-4)^2+(y^2xz-2)^2+(z^2xy-2)^2}<a}$

Comment: Looking again at your solution and remembering that this suppose to be a highschool inequality certainly the relation $b=min{1,a/54}$ does not belong to highschool curriculum. Can you suggest another way of getting around this little problem?

Comment: @user149368 See the update.

Comment: Thanks again for solving the second inequality and i wonder if the above inequalities do not represent the continuity at a certain point of a certain function, are they solvable?
For example:
Given $a>0$ find $b>0$ such that
$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<b\Longrightarrow |xy-6|<a$ 
OR
Given  $a>0$ find $b>0$ such that
$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<b\Longrightarrow |xy-7|<a$

Comment: @user149368 I think the answer is negative. For instance, in your first new inequality, since $1\cdot 2\ne 6$, there is so small $a$ (for instance, $a=1$) such that for an arbitrary $b>0$  there exist $x$ and $y$ such that 
$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<b$ but $|xy-6|>a$. In fact, it suffices to put $x=2$ and $y=1$.